# justifying inline-block elements using "text-align: justify" not working

Tags: html, css, text-align, text-justify

I am having the following Markup and I am trying to justify my list along my uls width like so:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

ul::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

Actually this is a common method to distribute items along their parents width. But for some reason it doesn't work in my current project. Any ideas you could share?

---

**UPDATE**

see this fiddle for a more authentic markup and style I am using:
https://jsfiddle.net/gqL8rqje/

Comment: What's the problem exactly? If it's the horizontal scroll, something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/ayNZrJ

Comment: yes thats working fine but somehow in my project environment it does not

Comment: It could be a css specificity issue. Try using `padding-left: 0 !important;` on the `ul` and see if that does it. You shouldn't use `!important` unless it's necessary, but that will tell you if it's a specificity issue. If that doesn't fix it, post enough code that you replicate the problem with the padding removed from the `ul`

Comment: What is the end result you are getting?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError the result looks like regular text-align: left;

Changing padding on the ul doesn't have any effect
check here for more authentic css and mark up that I am using: https://jsfiddle.net/gqL8rqje/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flexbox with space-between

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont want to use flexbox though

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem comes from your code indentation.
Indeed, the `display: inline-block` + `text-align: justify` works only if there are some separation in between elements.

In other words, the common method distribution will work for

```
<ul>
<li><a>some text</a></li>
<li><a>some text</a></li>
<li><a>some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

But it will not work for

```
<ul>
<li><a>some text</a></li><li><a>some text</a></li><li><a>some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't think there is a solution for your problem with such code indentation.
If you want it to work, you'll need to insert some break line between `<li>` tags when your page is generated.

Otherwise, the solution provided by @Gerard is the most bulletproof, even if you don't want to use flexbox, it will be the easiest way in your context.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `text-align-last: justify;` since with `text-align: justify;` the last line will always be left aligned, and in your case the only line IS the last line...

See your adapted fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bnwvj1q4/1/

And here your adapted snippet.

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align-last: justify;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I use a ::after element to stretch the last line so regular text-align: justify should do the job (https://jsfiddle.net/o2ywLbjx/).. but somehow it doesnt. No matter if I do it your way or my way, at least in my project, the fiddle works tho -.-

Comment: I cant replicate the issue in the fiddle... probably the problem might have something to do with some parent styles..

Comment: as `text-align-last` apparently is not supported on safari, is there an alternative that is better than this?